# Are there mapquest api methods that set or update a POI lat lng coordinate value?

Tags: javascript, geocoding, mouseover, mapquest

The `mouseover` event is processed to determine if an `MQA.Poi` should be displayed in the callback for the `mouseover` on the overlay on my map's viewport. I'm hoping to reuse a single `MQA.Poi` instead of re/instantiating one every time that it should be displayed.

I am basically looking to update the lat, lng of the marker with an API method similar to `self.poi.setInfoContentHTML(contentHTML)` for or `setValue` for MQA.Poi or any of its parents classes. I suppose it would be called something like setLatlng, but I find no such reference in the documentation.

Are there any mapquest api methods that you have used to set or update a `MQA.Poi` coordinate?

Comment: FYI, the MQA.POI docs for the MapQuest JS SDK is located at http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/api/MQA.Poi.html

Answer (score 2):

I was able to change a poi's lat/lng on `click` using the following code:

```
MQA.EventManager.addListener(poi, 'click', function(evt){
    this.setLatLng({lat:20,lng:20});
});
```

Found it by setting a breakpoint in the event function in Chrome and typing `this.` in the console to list available methods.